# making background dim in android

Tags: android, view

I want to develop a setting pannel in my project, like google play .It will show when i drage on the screen. And while it moves, the background goes dim.
Firt the screen is like this
[image: Firt the screen is like this]

When i slide the screen, the setting pannel moves to front while backgrounf goes slide dim
[image: When i slide the screen, the setting pannel moves to front while backgrounf goes slide dim.]

And when setting pannel comes to front cleasrly, background becomes more dim. Actually the background goes to dim gradually as the setting pannel moves to front.
[image: And when setting pannel comes to front cleasrly, background becomes more dim. Actually the background goes to dim gradually as the setting pannel moves to front.]

I am using android 4.0.3..how to do it. I need help to develop such view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the [Navigation Drawer](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html) UI design pattern.

[Here is a tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) explaining how to create one using the [DrawerLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html) class. It uses the support libraries so it will work on 4.0.3.